# How to design chatbox GUI using javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I would like to create a GUI Interface for a Chat application using javafx where the conversations are aligned like other social network applications. For example User1's conversations will appear always at the left side while User2's conversations always appear at right side.

Being a beginner at javafx, I have two ideas.

1. Create a list item and add conversations to that list and design each cell
2. Add new label controls into the layout pane for every conversation

What is the good idea to begin with for such a GUI?

I expect the GUI to be like this

```
hello
        hi, nice to meet you
same here
                how are you?
```

Please suggest the correct way of doing this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with a `VBox` and multiple `Labels`, but it will be **too greedy** since in JavaFX i don't think there is a **Control** allowing multiple text alignment. A `label` can contain text and at the same time its background is customizable (Shape,color,size..), and the `VBox` allows a vertical and ordered positioning of the Nodes.

Here is a small demonstration that you can perfect :

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.geometry.Pos;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.control.Button;
  import javafx.scene.control.Label;
  import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
  import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
  import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Launcher extends Application{

private Pane root = new Pane();
private Scene scene;

private final Button add = new Button("Add");
private final VBox chatBox = new VBox(5);
private List<Label> messages = new ArrayList<>();
private ScrollPane container = new ScrollPane();
private int index = 0;



@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

    initChatBox();
    root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Style.css").toExternalForm());
    root.getChildren().addAll(container,add);
    scene = new Scene(root,300,450);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}

private void initChatBox(){

    container.setPrefSize(216, 400);
    container.setContent(chatBox); 

    chatBox.getStyleClass().add("chatbox");

    add.setOnAction(evt->{

        messages.add(new Label("I'm a message"));

        if(index%2==0){

            messages.get(index).setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            System.out.println("1");

        }else{

            messages.get(index).setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
            System.out.println("2");

        }


        chatBox.getChildren().add(messages.get(index));
        index++;

    });



}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args); 
}

}
```

Style (I preferred to put the properties in style but free to you to put them where you want) :

```
  .chatbox{

  -fx-background-color:#333333;
  -fx-min-height:400px;
  -fx-min-width:200px; 

  }

  .label{

  -fx-background-color:purple;
  -fx-text-fill:white;
  -fx-pref-height:20px;
  -fx-pref-width:200px; 

  }

 .button{

 -fx-background-color:purple;
 -fx-text-fill:white;
 -fx-pref-height:25px;
 -fx-pref-width:50px;
 -fx-translate-x:75;
 -fx-translate-y:410; 

 }
```

Overview :

[image: Help]

Good luck !

Comment: If that's the answer you wanted you can mark it, otherwise you can wait for other better answers ! ;)

Comment: Let us wait for any other better approaches if available for sometime :)

Comment: @SathyamoorthyR It's actually been a year, you can remark other better answer, don't hesitate to mark this as the solution, i found this very helpful, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the layout as more data is just feels like the wrong approach.  Use a ListView and you can just deal with the messages in an ObservableList.  A tiny amount of change to the standard ListCell styling will remove the alternating colour backgrounds, and it won't look like a ListView any more.

The easiest way to handle positioning to the left or to the right is to put the message text in an HBox and then set the alignment of the HBox to Pos.CENTER_RIGHT or Pos.CENTER_LEFT.

```
public class Chatter extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    ObservableList<ChatEntry> messages;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        messages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Button localButton = new Button("Local");
        Button remoteButton = new Button("Remote");
        ListView<ChatEntry> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setCellFactory(list -> new ChatCell());
        listView.setItems(messages);
        localButton.setOnAction(evt -> messages.add(new ChatEntry(textField.getText(), MessageType.LOCAL)));
        remoteButton.setOnAction(evt -> messages.add(new ChatEntry(textField.getText(), MessageType.REMOTE)));
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(10, listView, new HBox(remoteButton, textField, localButton)));
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/css/samples.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    enum MessageType {
        LOCAL, REMOTE
    }


    static class ChatCell extends ListCell<ChatEntry> {

        HBox graphic = new HBox();
        Text message = new Text();

        public ChatCell() {
            graphic.getChildren().add(message);
            getStyleClass().add("custom-list-cell");
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(ChatEntry item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (!empty && (item != null)) {
                message.setText(item.textProperty().get());
                graphic.setAlignment(item.typeProperty().get().equals(MessageType.REMOTE) ? Pos.CENTER_LEFT : Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                setGraphic(graphic);
            } else {
                message.setText("");
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }


    static class ChatEntry {
        private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        private final ObjectProperty<MessageType> type = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public ChatEntry(String text, MessageType type) {
            this.text.set(text);
            this.type.set(type);
        }

        public StringProperty textProperty() {
            return text;
        }

        public ObjectProperty<MessageType> typeProperty() {
            return type;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the CSS entry:

```
.custom-list-cell:odd {
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Layout Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvuCU.png)

**Create** `GridPane` **with 3 columns having percentage width** `25.0` `50.0` **and** `25.0`.**

```
For sender:
Place content at column index 1 with column span 2. Apply suitable fill.

For receiver:
Place content at column index 0 with column span 2.Apply suitable fill.
```

---

---

In Fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" vgap="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Example.ChatController">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" percentWidth="25.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" percentWidth="50.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" percentWidth="25.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <VBox minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="0.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
               <children>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Me" />
                  <TextFlow style="-fx-background-color: DODGERBLUE; -fx-background-radius: 10;" textAlignment="JUSTIFY">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <opaqueInsets>
                        <Insets />
                     </opaqueInsets>
                     <children>
                        <Text fill="WHITE" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Sender" textAlignment="RIGHT" />
                     </children>
                  </TextFlow>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="05:35 AM" />
               </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </padding>
            </VBox>
            <VBox maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="0.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <children>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="You" />
                  <TextFlow style="-fx-background-color: lightgray; -fx-background-radius: 10;" textAlignment="JUSTIFY">
                     <children>
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Receiver" />
                     </children>
                     <opaqueInsets>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </opaqueInsets>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </TextFlow>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="05:36 AM" />
               </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </padding></VBox>
         </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>
      </GridPane>
```

---

For Dynamically adding Receiver and Sender box:

```
    //Controller.java

@FXML
private GridPane chatGridPane;

private void chatRecordOnChanged() {
            model.chatRecordProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldRecord, newRecord) -> {

            final Text agent = newRecord.getRecordAgent(); //Me or You
            Text recordMessage = newRecord.getRecordMessage(); 
            final var messageFlow = new TextFlow(recordMessage);

            if (newRecord.isSent()) {
                recordMessage.getStyleClass().add("sentMessageContent");
                messageFlow.getStyleClass().addAll("sentMessage", "message");
            } else {
                recordMessage.getStyleClass().add("receivedMessageContent");
                messageFlow.getStyleClass().addAll("receivedMessage", "message");
            }
            messageFlow.setLineSpacing(2);

            final var recordDate = newRecord.getRecordDate();

            final var columnIndex = newRecord.isSent() ? 1 : 0;
            final var columnSpan = 2;

            final var rowIndex = chatGridPane.getRowCount();
            final var rowSpan = 1;

            final VBox vBox = getVBox(agent, messageFlow, recordDate);
            chatGridPane.add(vBox, columnIndex, rowIndex, columnSpan, rowSpan);
        });
    }

private static VBox getVBox(Node... nodes) {
        final var vBox = new VBox(nodes);
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        return vBox;
    }
```

---

```
<ScrollPane fx:id="chatScrollPane" fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="NEVER" pannable="true" prefHeight="209.0" prefWidth="425.0">
           <content>
              <GridPane fx:id="chatGridPane" style="-fx-background-color: WHITE;" vgap="10.0">
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                 </padding>
                 <columnConstraints>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" percentWidth="25.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" percentWidth="50.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" percentWidth="25.0" />
                 </columnConstraints>
              </GridPane>
           </content>
        </ScrollPane>
```

---

```
//Model.java
public SimpleObjectProperty<Chat.UIChatRecord> chatRecordProperty() {
    return chatRecord;
}

public synchronized void setChatRecord(Chat.UIChatRecord uiChatRecord) {
    Platform.runLater(()->
            this.chatRecord.set(uiChatRecord)
    );
}
```

---

```
//Chat.java
private void send(String message) {
   
    uiModel.setChatRecord(new UIChatRecord(State.SEND,ZonedDateTime.now(), agent, message));
}

private void receive(String message) {
    
    uiModel.setChatRecord(new UIChatRecord(State.RECEIVE,ZonedDateTime.now(), agent, message));
}

enum State {

    SEND, RECEIVE
}

public static class UIChatRecord {
    private final Text recordDate;
    private final Text recordAgent;
    private final Text recordMessage;
    private final State state;


    public UIChatRecord(State state, ZonedDateTime zdt, Agent agent , String message) {

        this.state = state;
        this.recordAgent = new Text(agent.getDescriptiveName());
        this.recordDate = new Text(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh : mm a ")));
        this.recordMessage = new Text(message);
    }

    public boolean isSent() {
        return (state== State.SEND);
    }

    public Text getRecordDate() {
        return recordDate;
    }

    public Text getRecordMessage() {
        return recordMessage;
    }

    public Text getRecordAgent() {
        return recordAgent;
    }
}
```

---

```
 .message {
    -fx-background-radius:10;
    -fx-padding:10;
}

.sentMessage {
    -fx-background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.sentMessageContent {
    -fx-fill: white;
}

.receivedMessage {
    -fx-background-color: lightgray;
}

.receivedMessageContent {
    -fx-fill: black;
}
```